# My JavaScript/AJAX function only works while debugging

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, debugging

I am not very familiar with JavaScript and AJAX.

I am developing a webpage that displays information return by a §.getJSON / JQuery request. But this function only works, when I start debugging. I know that the debugger corrects the timing and scope from other post on this topic. But I cannot find my mistake. I do not realy need a long explaination, because as I said before I am not very familiar with JavaScript/AJAX. This is the script-part in the page (you can ignore the addDropDown() and the departmentSelected() functions(as far as i know)):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var isSelected = [];

$(addDropDown);

function addDropDown(){
    $.getJSON("./api/persence/departments/all", function(data, status){
        if(status !== "success"){
            alert(status);
        }else{
            var dropdownHead = "<button class='btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle' type='button' data-toggle='dropdown'>Abteilungen<span class='caret'><\/span><\/button>";
            var dropdownBody = "<ul class='dropdown-menu'>";
                            var i;
            for(i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
                dropdownBody = dropdownBody + "<li><a href='javascript:departmentSelected(" + i + "," + data[i].departmentId + ");'>";
                dropdownBody = dropdownBody + data[i].departmentName;
                dropdownBody = dropdownBody + " - ";
                dropdownBody = dropdownBody + data[i].departmentCity;
                dropdownBody = dropdownBody + "<\/a><\/li>";
            }
            dropdownBody = dropdownBody + "<\/ul>";
            dropdownHead = dropdownHead + dropdownBody;
            $("#dropdown-list").append(dropdownHead);
                            isSelected.length = i + 1;
        }

    });
    }

    function departmentSelected(position, value){
        if((isSelected[position] !== value)){
            isSelected[position] = value;
        }else{
            isSelected[position] = "false";
        }
        loadTable();
    }

    function loadTable(){
        var tHead = "<br><div class='table-responsive'><table class='table'><thead><tr><th>#</th><th>Name<\/th><th>Beruf<\/th><th>Anwesend<\/th><th>Arbeitsplatz<\/th><\/tr><\/thead>";
        var tBody = "<tbody>";
        for(var i = 0; i < isSelected.length; i++){
                        var counter = 0;
            if(isSelected[i] !== "false"){
                $.getJSON("./api/persence/departments/" + isSelected[i]).then(function(result, status){
                    if(status !== "success"){
                        alert(status);
                    }else{

                        for(var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
                            var employee = result[i];
                            tBody = tBody + "<tr> <td>" + counter + "<\/td>";
                            tBody = tBody + "<td>" + employee.academicTitle + " " + employee.lastName + " " + employee.firstName + "<\/td>";
                            tBody = tBody + "<td>" + employee.job + "<\/td>";
                            tBody = tBody + "<td>";
                            if(employee.persenceStatus === "Y"){
                                tBody = tBody + employee.persenceSince;
                            }else{
                                                             //   if(employee.absenceReason !== null){
                                tBody = tBody + employee.absenceReason;
                                                               // }
                                                                //else{
                                                                  //  tBody = tBody + " ";
                                                                //}
                            }
                            tBody = tBody + "<\/td>";
                            tBody = tBody + "<td>" + employee.workplace + "<\/td>";
                                                            tBody = tBody + "<\/tr>";
                                                            counter++;
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        }
        tBody = tBody + "<\/tbody> <\/table> <\/div>";
        tHead = tHead + tBody;
        document.getElementById("outputTable").innerHTML = tHead;
        }
```

My Problem: I can not find what I have done wrong in this scriptpart, because the debugger (firebug) is able to optimize the code while debugging so it works perfectly fine. But if I am not in debug-mode, only the "head-line" of the table is displayed (the information is missing).

Thanks for your help.

Comment: When you are not debugging is there any error at console?

Comment: The console only displays that the request (e.g. GET: http://localhost:8080/PersenceProject/api/persence/departments/2) was successful (code 200). And if I open the request in another tab, I get the correct JSON. So I think the else-part of the function does not work, but I do not know why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I solved the problem myself: I had to put the following part into the function called by the jQuery request (function(result, status).....)

> tBody = tBody + "</tbody> </table> </div>";
>           tHead = tHead + tBody;
>           document.getElementById("outputTable").innerHTML = tHead;

Answer (score 0):

This problem is about the finding element in DOM. Sometimes Js faster than DOM and Js can't find specific element in html DOM. You need to define js code in onLoad.

```
$(function() {
  $(addDropDown);
});
```

OR

```
$(document).ready(function(){  
    $(addDropDown); 
});
```

**Inportant Info:** If you include jQuery don't use JS specific functions. Sometimes it crash with jquery. Just use jQuery functions.

Example:
*not good* : `document.getElementById("outputTable")`
*good* : `'$.("#outputTable")'`

Comment: 1. Thanks for your help. I did what you said: `$("#outputTable").html(tHead);` Before that call I added `console.log(tHead);` but the variable is not printed into the console. So I do not know why?